# PHP retrieving an integer value from $_GET

Tags: php, security, get

Consider for a moment the following situation.

```
www.example.com/post.php?delete=3
```

The generated link above would delete the post with an id of 3. As you can imagine, I would be retrieving the id like this:

```
$id = (int) $_GET['delete']; //casting to int to make sure that 
                             //the value is an integer - is  
                             //it safe enough?
if($user->isAdmin()) {

  //proceed with deletion from database - SQL queries, etc

}
```

**My question:** is it safe to simply cast the `$_GET` value to an integer and be done with it? I'm aware that we shouldn't use GET data for database related operations, but is it always the case? (Let's pretend that the `isAdmin()` method correctly checks whether the current user is an admin).

What are the possible caveats of such `$_GET` data usage regarding **security**?

Comment: If you know it's supposed to be an integer and your code checks for zero values then this is a good practice.

Comment: as long as you dont mind me manually changing it to 4 or 5 or 6;   your safe

Comment: You could use [`intval()`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

Comment: The number represents the id of the post, so substituting it with a different value would delete a different post. Such functionality would be open only to admins (hence the isAdmin() method), so I guess it should be pretty safe. However, I'm a bit paranoid about security, so let's see if someone comes up with any security issues.

Comment: @crush why `intval()` over `(int)` ?

Comment: @dagon `intval` is more forgiving

Comment: Forgiving? What do you mean?

Comment: Look at the examples in the link I posted.

Comment: By the way, @JohnConde, what do you mean by "...and your code checks for zero values" - what could possibly happen with a zero value?

Comment: If you convert a non-numeric value to an integer you will get a zero for that value. That may or may not cause problems for your software if that is considered a valid value or not. If it is a valid value then casting could break things or cause unexpected results.

Comment: `Casting to int to make sure that the value is an integer - is it safe enough?` - Not quite. You should sanitize (or perhaps validate too) the $_GET before passing it on your DB layer.

Comment: Well, seems I'm wrong (happens often). `intval()` and casting to `int` are synonymous. The only difference is that `intval()` allows you to specify a base.

Comment: @dqlopez I'm passing an integer to the DB layer. What could possibly happen? I'm making sure my value is an integer and that it is > 0. Why do I need to perform other checks?

Comment: @crush: It's an extra function call, so I guess `intval` is slighly slower too (not by a noticeable margin though).

Comment: You should be using a DB abstraction layer that sanitizes inputs.  Let code do the heavily lifting for you so that you don't have to worry about every string/integer/whatever that gets sent to the DB.

Comment: But is it really a security risk in the situation portrayed in the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not safe.

The problem is not the casting of the value, but the use of `GET` instead of `POST`. If you use links for your delete options and one of your admins uses for example firefox with the fasterfox extension installed, all links will be pre-fetched, effectively wiping out your database or a part of it, depending on how many links you are showing.

Although I don't think link-prefetching is very common, you really should use `POST` to avoid the problems it causes with your system.

And if you don't use links, switching to `POST` is even easier so there is really no reason not to do it.

By the way, if you are `paranoid over security` I assume you already use prepared statements, so casting to `int` or not will not make much of a difference anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. One more question - would it be safe to use POST and cast to an integer? Seems like a secure solution to me.

Comment: @doitmyway Yes, but like I said, if you use prepared statements, casting would not add much value. Although it is always nice to know with what kind of variable you are dealing exactly....

Comment: I'm using the ADO db layer that comes with concrete5, so I suppose it's safe then.

Answer (score 0):

The security of your specific method is fine.

By casting, you have limited the input to be a specific type which prevents flaws assuming that your system doesn't break on "-1" and that PHP doesn't explode when you cast "Malware" to an int.

Have you looked at filter_var? If you have an up to date version of php this can let you validate the variable (of types other than int and of int ranges) as well.

Comment: I'm aware of filter_var. The value that is needed is an integer - I try not to use GET requests for strings for example.